# i have been working on robot framework on virtual machine (windows 7). it gives error- <urlopen error [Errno 11004 >

Tags: virtual-machine, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

i have been working on robot framework on virtual machine (windows 7). **My test cases were working fine till yesterday.** Now when i try to open a browser with pretty much any URL,the browser window opens dead and on cmd, it gives error- urlopen error [Errno 11004 . Help!!

here is the code which i am trying:-

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Library  OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***

${url}       https://www.google.com                
${btn}       u_0_4
${id}        email
${pass}      pass

*** Testcases ***
func

    Open Browser  ${url}   ff
    Maximize Browser Window
    ${var} =  Get Location
    Log  ${var}  WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

your Robot/Selenium script look fine.
You might have a network configuration issue on your machine.
Try to "ping www.google.com" from the windows VM.
You should get something like:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ping www.google.com
Pinging www.google.com [173.194.45.80] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 173.194.45.80: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=57
Reply from 173.194.45.80: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=57
Reply from 173.194.45.80: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=57
```

If not, then you have to review network config on the VM

Comment: This is what i am getting:

    C:\Users\ewaibch\Desktop\robot>ping www.google.com

    Pinging www.google.com [74.125.143.104] with 32 bytes of data:
    Reply from 74.125.143.104: bytes=32 time=459ms TTL=29
    Reply from 74.125.143.104: bytes=32 time=454ms TTL=29
    Reply from 74.125.143.104: bytes=32 time=458ms TTL=29
    Reply from 74.125.143.104: bytes=32 time=442ms TTL=29

    Ping statistics for 74.125.143.104:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
    Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 442ms, Maximum = 459ms, Average = 453ms

Comment: sorry, m not very good at formatting at stackoverflow... i even got a new system image on my VM, still the same situation :(

Comment: ok, so network is OK. What happens when you open firefox on google url? Does it work well? (I mean outside or Robot/Selenium)

Comment: net is working fine outside.. but with the automation, browser opens dead, just blanck..if i try to use this window even manually, it is irresponsive.I got new system image installed and
it is working fine ryt now, but that is not a solution... next time i hit the same problem, i would like to choose a real solution.